# Create Table in MySql from User Input Value

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

I am trying to crate a table in MySQL database in which no of fields are variable and their sizes are constant. Is it possible to create database from the user input values?

I have created two JSP files

**readData.jsp**

```
<form method="post" action="makeDB.jsp" name="testForm">        

        Name <input class="input_txt" id="surName" name="surName" type="text" maxlength="30">                           
        Type <select id="mySelect"  name="surType">
                <option>Choose one:</option>
                <option>Voting</option>
                <option>Application</option>
                <option>Invitation</option>                         
            </select>               
        Description<textarea class="input_txt" id="surDescrip" name="surDescrip" rows="2" cols="30" maxlength="1200">
        </textarea>

        Question <input class="input_txt" id="Ques" name="Ques" type="text" maxlength="1020"><br /><br />
            Answer Option 1 : <input class="input_txt" id="opt1" name="AnsOption1" type="text" maxlength="100"><br />
            Answer Option 2 : <input class="input_txt" id="opt2" name="AnsOption2" type="text" maxlength="100"><br />
            Answer Option 3 : <input class="input_txt" id="opt3" name="AnsOption3" type="text" maxlength="100"><br />
            Answer Option 4 : <input type="hidden" id="OptionCount" name="OptionCount">


        <input id="sub" type="submit" value="Start Creating DB">

</form>
```

**makeDB.jsp**

```
<%!
    // Variables 
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;      
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/crDB";
    static final String USER_NM = "foo";
    static final String PASS_WRD = "bar";
    static final String MyDB_Name = "Something";

    public void makeDB(String MyDB_Name, String SURVEY_NAME, String SURVEY_TYPE, String SURVEY_DESCRIPTION, String QUESTION, String ANS1, String ANS2, String ANS3) {

    try {

            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER_NM, PASS_WRD);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "CREATE TABLE "+MyDB_Name+" ("+SURVEY_NAME+")........."; 
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);

            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        }  catch (Exception e) {

            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }    

    } 

%>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, whats wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Creating table is not something else and it's also a simple sql query like any other `select/update`  query you can just execute that query.

And more over look at [`prepared statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and use it. Do not execute plain sql query like that It may causes sql injection.

Comment: can you please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139701/get-sqlexception-error-before-giving-the-user-input-in-jsp-page